# Check if user has been authenticated today

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and i want to check if the user has been authenticated today so he can collect the points.
The day must start at 00:00:00 and end at 00:00:00
What can be the logic behind that ?
Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add  last_login_date column in your users table and in any time the user has authenticated you shold update this column and you can check if the user authenticated today user compare beetween today date and last_login_date 
you can use carbon api

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2019-10-01');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2019-10-30');

$check = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->between($startDate,$endDate);
```